# jquery keypress event for cmd+s AND ctrl+s

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, macos

Using one of the examples from a previous question I have:

```
$(window).keypress(function(event) {
    if (!(event.which == 115 && event.ctrlKey) && !(event.which == 19)) return true;
    $("form input[name=save]").click();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Is it also possible to change this to work for the Mac cmd key?

I have tried `(!(event.which == 115 && (event.cmdKey || event.ctrlKey)) && !(event.which == 19))` but this didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I capture COMMAND+S in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833325/how-can-i-capture-commands-in-jquery) <might help>`:)`

Comment: Key-Events are pretty inconsistent between browsers and OS. Just code an small example and check which keys and modifiers are triggered when pressing cmd+S.

Comment: I can't say this for sure but as a general rule I think you want to avoid changing the default behaviors of the browser (ctrl+s/cmd+s === "Save Page As")

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the **event.metaKey** to detect the Command key

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 115 && (event.ctrlKey||event.metaKey)|| (event.which == 19)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // do stuff
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Typo missing bracket. I tried to edit this so but get error: "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?" stupid stackoverflow

Comment: unfortunately this does not work for me in chrome(Version 27.0.1453.110). it always opens the "save as" dialog... - CTRL + S works on the other hand

Comment: The answer is good but the question is bad - we shouldn't generally override default behaviors in browsers (meta+s === "save"). Saving a webpage isn't a particularly useful thing to do, but it's best to not pointlessly defy user expectations.

Comment: Jon z, what if you want to paste text inside a canvas element? It's very useful.

Answer (score 4):

For detecting `ctrl+s` and `cmd+s`, you can use this way:

[**Working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/9ytfe/5/)

**jQuery:**

```
var isCtrl = false;
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
 if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=false;
}).keydown(function (e) {
    if(e.which == 17) isCtrl=true;
    if(e.which == 83 && isCtrl == true) {
        alert('you pressed ctrl+s');
    return false;
 }
});
```

[source (includes all keyboard shorcuts and buttons)](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/using-keyboard-shortcuts-in-javascript)

Comment: Nice, can you explain why this is a better solution than the other answer?

Comment: On my Macbook ( Chrome and Safari ) cmd+s doesn't work until you press ctr+s.  Then both work.  Weird.

Comment: @T.BrianJones same thing happend to me on different browsers. I guess browser's `save` function prevents our function /:

Comment: @BarlasApaydin - DannyR's answer worked for my application in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93695/best-cross-browser-method-to-capture-ctrls-with-jquery/14180949#comment25956719_14180949

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    if ((event.which == 115 || event.which == 83) && (event.ctrlKey||event.metaKey)|| (event.which == 19)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // do stuff
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`keydown` is the proper event to listen to as this is the one that most applications are hooked into (especially browsers).

Also, there's no reason to use jQuery for this these days. In modern JS:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if ((e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey) && e.key === "s") {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do what you want here
  }
});
```