# Permission denied IE8 on jquery keypress (enter)

Tags: php, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

IE8 keeps throwing error **Permission denied**:

- jquery-1.7.2.min.js | Line:2, Char:21695
- jquery-1.7.2.js     | Line:1712, Char:4

(depend on which version I use).

It happens when I press enter ([function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742349/focus-on-next-tabindex-of-html-element-onenter-keypress-by-jquery/11205952#11205952) on 'Enter' jump around tabindexes). And it happens only on specific server and specific PC group who uses IE8.

[EDIT]
It happens when calling

```
$("[TabIndex='"+tabindex+"']").focus()
$("[TabIndex='"+tabindex+"']").blur()
```

Full code

```
//WALKING with ENTER
        var tabindex = 1; //start tabindex || 150 is last tabindex
        $(document).keypress(function(event) {
            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if(keycode == '13') { //onEnter
                if($("[TabIndex='"+tabindex+"']").attr('id') == 'submit_btn'){ //if on 'sbm - button' click!
                    $("#submit_btn").click();
            return false;
                };
                $("[TabIndex='"+tabindex+"']").blur()//.removeClass('highlight_input');
                tabindex++;
                //while element exist or it's readonly and tabindex not reached max do
                while(($("[TabIndex='"+tabindex+"']").length == 0 || $("[TabIndex='"+tabindex+"']:not([readonly])").length == 0) && tabindex != 150 ){
                    tabindex++;
                }
                if(tabindex == 150){ tabindex = 1 } //reseting tabindex if finished
                $("[TabIndex='"+tabindex+"']").focus()//.addClass('highlight_input');
                return false;
            }
        });
```

I can reproduce this error only Logging off/re-logging Windows(XP) -> going back to this interface and pressing 'Enter'. After F5: everything works fine.

Has anyone already experienced something like this before?

Comment: check this, it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502122/jquery-keypress-event-for-cmds-and-ctrls/11502343#11502343

Comment: that way wont return permission denied on ie8

Comment: At this moment I can't get access to the test-srv, but I think that the problem is not how the event's "onEnter" been helded, but how jquery reacts on selectors like $("[TabIndex='"+tabindex+"']").focus(). Anyway I shall try your solutinon once i get to srv. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem occurred when **blur()** or **focus()** ware called, so i had to find workaround. Task was to call (almost) pure javascript instead of calling jquery focus/blur.

```
//Focus workaround for IE8 (exception)
var elid = $('input[tabindex='+tabindex+']').attr("id");
var element = document.getElementById(elid); 
element.blur(); 

var elid = $('input[tabindex='+tabindex+']').attr("id");
var element = document.getElementById(elid); 
element.focus();
```

instead of

```
$("[TabIndex='"+tabindex+"']").blur()
$("[TabIndex='"+tabindex+"']").blur()
```

Drop a comment if you have any questions 
or you have faced the same problem.